# Vertical list of radio buttons

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Somehow Material Design Lite only gives examples of horizontal radio buttons in the docs: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/radio

This is not enough if you want to be mobile, and your labels are several words in length.

Anyway here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBKPeY

[image]

I tried to separate items by `<br>` and wrapping them in `<p>` but it doesn't help. I guess some ninja css trick can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you could just revise your style rule for `mdl-radio` on mobile devices with:

```
.mdl-radio {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

Notice `display: block` & `margin-bottom: 32px`.

Comment: Thanks. `margin-bottom: 32px` might break for longer labels?

Comment: It should still maintain 32px between the current label and the label beneath it. Longer labels shouldn't change that. Glad to help!

Comment: And the `display: block` ensures that each label has it's own line in the document.

Comment: I modified that code pen with your solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBKPeY -- as you see when the label spans three lines -- it doesn't fit. That is because of hardcoded `32px`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It looks like we've got a `height: 24px` that's allowing labels to overlap. Change that to `height: auto` and you can actually get rid of the `margin-bottom: 32px' altogether.